# Selecting arc/element

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, sunburst-diagram

In the [sunburst](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/sunburst.html), how can I make code select a root arc, just after all arcs was generated?

For example, in the code:

```
var first_arc = ""
.json("../data/flare.json", function(json) {
   var path = vis.data([json]).selectAll("path")
       .data(partition.nodes)
     .enter().append("path")
       .attr("display", function(d) { return d.depth ? null : "none"; })
       .attr("d", arc)
       .attr("t_name", function(d) {return d.name})
       .style("fill-rule", "evenodd")
       .on("click", function(d)...
```

it would be passed as "d" to the "function" on click on the middle arc.

(its data goes first in the json file)

**Update 1**: Changing the code like so…

```
.style("fill-rule", function(d) {
   if (first_arc == "") first_arc = d; return "evenodd"})
```

…solved the problem, it returns `object`:

```
name: "flare"
children: Array[10]
...
```

but this solution doesn't look right and isn't general.

**Update 2**: I tried several selects, for example:

```
first_arc = d3.select("[name='flare']")
```

it usually returns `array`:

```
0: null
length: 1
parentNode: HTMLHtmlElement
__proto__: Array[0]
```

or "undefined"

**Update 3**:

```
first_arc = d3.select("[t_name='flare']")
```

returns `array` of size 1 with children:

```
0: SVGPathElement
   __data__: Object
```

, where `__data__` is the object I'm after, but I can't manage to select it.

Comment: To be clear: are you trying to have code select the element, or are you asking about the user clicking on an arc and processing that directly?

Comment: Trying to have code select the element, straight after the arc generation was done.

Comment: I still don't understand what your question/problem is, then. You would use the [`d3.select()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-d3_select) method. Have you tried that? If so, what is your code, and what error did you get (and what were you expecting instead)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root node is the one with a "depth" attribute set to 0. So you can say:

```
d3.selectAll("path").filter(function(d) { return d.depth === 0; })
```

Your attempts above weren't working because [D3 uses CSS3 to select elements](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections). So you can only use d3.select and d3.selectAll with [CSS3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) selectors i.e. you can't access the data bound to each element this way. The way to filter on the bound data is to use [selection.filter](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-filter).

[D3 selections](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections) are literally an array of elements, see the "Operating on Selections" section.

Lastly, you can get the bound `__data__` property for an element using [selection.datum()](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-datum).

Comment: Thanks! This is extremely useful. Though, the selection you mentioned returns same object as `d3.select("[t_name='flare']")`.

Comment: I don't know what t_name is - is that an attribute that you've set? I've added some information to the answer about what D3 selections are and retrieving bound data.

Comment: Regarding `t_name` - found this attribute of svg arcs using Element Browser in Developer Tools.

Comment: My apologies - it was me who added the t_name attribute. Corrected the code in the question.