# D3 sort function always passes undefined arguments

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

Using D3 2.4.2, I create a number of path elements like so:

```
for (var i = 0; i < pathIndices.length; i++) {
  graph.append("svg:path")
    .style("stroke", colors[pathIndices[i]])
    .style("stroke-width", "2.5px")
    .style("fill", "none")
    .attr("class", PATH_CLASS)
    .attr("id", PATH_ID_PREFIX + pathIndices[i])
    .attr("d", lineFunc(data))[0];
}
```

They all draw to the screen as expected.  Later on, I want to bring one of them to the front when the user makes some input, so I have an event handler that does this:

```
var pathToHighlight = selectPath(pathIndex);
var paths = d3.selectAll("." + PATH_CLASS);
paths.sort(
  function(a, b) {
    if (a === pathToHighlight) {
      return -1;
    }
    else if (b === pathToHighlight) {
      return 1;
    }
    else {
      return 0;
    }
  }
);
```

Setting breakpoints in Chrome indicates that my path selections here are successful (`paths` is an array of SVGPathElements).  But the code does nothing, and setting breakpoints inside the sort function shows that `a` and `b` are always undefined.  Going up into the d3 code, I see that when the internal function `d3_selection_sortComparator` calls my comparator with the appropriate arguments, except they're ANDed with their own undefined `__data__` members, which causes `undefined` to be passed in:

```
// a and b are correct, but a.__data__ and b.__data__ are undefined
return comparator(a && a.__data__, b && b.__data__);
```

What am I doing wrong here?  My paths draw correctly to the screen, so it seems like they should have the correct data.  Right?

Edit: Images:

[image: Contents of path]

[image: parameters a and b are undefined]

Comment: So, `paths` is a native Array and does not contain `undefined` items?

Comment: It looks like a native Array in the Chrome debugger.  There are no undefined items, just the expected svg path elements.

Comment: Afaik many objects can look like arrays in the debugger. Check its prototype chain, and test `paths.sort === [].sort`

Comment: `console.log(typeof paths);` gives me `object`.  To be fair, so does `console.log(typeof []);`.  The D3 documentation says it expects a "selection" to be returned from its selectAll().  Your `paths.sort === [].sort` gives me false.

Answer (score 5):

You're using [`selection.sort`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#sort) when it sounds like you're expecting [`Array.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). The `selection.sort` method is used for sorting a selection based on the *data* bound to elements `a` and `b`. If your elements don't have data bound to them, then this won't work. If you want to sort a selection based on something else (like testing that one element reference is equal to another), you should grab the array of elements from the selection before calling `.sort()` like so:

```
// `paths` is a Selection
var paths = d3.selectAll("." + PATH_CLASS);
// `pathElements` is an Array
var pathElements = paths[0];

pathElements.sort(function(a,b) {
  // now `a` and `b` are Element references
  // ...
})
```

Then you would have to take the extra step of matching the DOM order to the order of the resulting array.

That said, if you just want to bring `pathToHighlight` to the front, a better way to approach this is just to re-append that single element to the DOM.

If `pathToHighlight` is a selection you would do this:

```
var el = pathToHighlight.node();
el.parentNode.appendChild(el);
```

or, if it's already an Element reference, you can just do:

```
pathToHighlight.parentNode.appendChild(pathToHighlight);
```

Answer (score 2):

As @jshanley mentioned, the elements in your selection does not have any data bound to them (__data__ attribute is undefined). The function passed to selection.sort will receive what data is bound to the element and in your case it is undefined.

You can bind the selected elements to data with the datum() function.

Try this:

```
paths.datum(function () { return this };).sort(...)
```

This will bind the element to itself and you will be able to reference it in the sort function.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try `.datum()` function instead of `.__data__`?

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-datum

> selection.datum([value])
>   Gets or sets the bound data for each selected element

Comment: I may have had similar problem to yours here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11688615/selecting-arc-element/11744349

Comment: I'm not setting `a.__data__`, that code came from inside d3, and reveals that the `comparator(...)`, which is the callback for my sort function, is getting `undefined` for `a` and `b` because, while `a` and `b` are defined as I would expect, their member `__data__` is not.

Comment: And they are ANDed together.  `(a && a.__data__)`